# How do I prevent GAE from ungzipping a gzipped xml feed?

Tags: http, google-app-engine, cron, gzip

I have a script on GAE that requests an XML feed from a partner that's typically 40MB but only 5MB gzipped.  GAE is automatically unzipping this content and throwing an error that the response is too big:

> HTTP response was too large: 46677241. The limit is: 33554432.

The script is setup to uncompress the response itself.  How do I prevent GAE from getting in the way and breaking?

Here's the response header from my partner:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Expires: Wed, 27 Jun 2012 05:42:07 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=10368000
Content-Type: application/x-gzip
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Last-Modified: Wed, 22 Feb 2012 11:06:09 GMT
Content-Length: 5263323
Date: Tue, 28 Feb 2012 05:42:07 GMT
Server: lighttpd
X-Cache: MISS from static01
X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from static01:80
Via: 1.0 static01:80 (squid)
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your partner's server responds with plain XML, because it thinks that http-client sending requests (i.e. GAE URL Fetch service) does not support gzipping. Hence "response was too large" error.

To announce that you actually want to receive gzipped content you need to set `Accept-Encoding: gzip` header when using URL fetch service.

Comment: the filename being fetched actually ends in "xml.gz".   thanks, though, I'll add that to the request anyway and see if it helps.